# Como crear un sistema de gestion de archivos en Blazor

Tags: asp.net, web, blazor

como se podria crear un sistema de gestion de archivos y carpetas en blazor? mi duda principal es la navegacion, como se podria navegar dentro de una carpeta y ver su contenido? los datos estan almacenados en sql server, y de manera manual inserte los datos para prueba y pude recuperar la carpeta principal, pero como hago la navegacion dentro de ella?. Comparto los datos insertados en la bd.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien, para obtener los datos desde la db los parametros solicitados son CustomerId y FolderParentId, donde este ultimo es fundamental para indicar que si es o no un folder principal, si es 0 es la carpeta Principal inicial, y a medida que se inserte dentro una carpeta cualquier otra carpeta este cambia su id.

Tambien, les comparto los datos obtenidos desde Postman.
[image: https://localhost:7115/api/folder?customerId=1&folderParentId=0]

Por otro lado, se que se podria utilizar un componente razor reutilizable para desplegar la vista, pero como funcionaria la navegacion en ese caso?

Comment: Creas un componente Blazor que actúe como Page y que reciba como parámetro (puedes ser como querystring) la id del `FolderParentId`, con esa Id consultas todas las carpetas cuyo padre corresponda.